# Numeric textboxes in Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to have a feature like a Numeric textbox in MVC which has all the validations in place(Do not want to use Kendo as it has all kinds of Validation probblems) ?

Comment: Have you looked for [html numeric textbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=html%20numeric%20textbox)? This is not mvc specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate with javascript like this:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844)

Comment: Thanks for the response but Currency also involves checking for decimals and while displaying it should format with commas. Ex 100,000$

Comment: For currency you can try these libs: [money.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js) or [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,  The third  parameter are your `Html attributes`.

```
@Html.TextBox("Age", null, new {type ="number", min="1" max="5", id="age"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the input type to number

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.numberProperty, new { @type = "number" })
```